# different type of mapping variables in std::map

Tags: c++

I want to store an event and its subscriber and publisher in a map. Here map key is the event and mapped value is subscriber and the publisher. But the type of publisher and subscriber are different. But map gives only a certain type of mapped value.

How to handle this things or is there any other data structure for it??

Comment: Can't you just make a pair of the publisher and subscriber? `struct PubSubPair { Publisher pub; Subscriber sub; };`

Comment: This is the last option I have thought John. Since speed is a major factor for me, I want a direct mapping if possible.

Comment: There's no speed loss at all in what I've proposed. The mapping is still 'direct', it's not as if I've added a pointer or something.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is a publisher and a subscriber for each event so probably it is best to have your map from event to `std::pair` of publisher and subscriber. This way you will also preserve the relation between the two.